# Error when I try to launch website in IIS: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to launch a website in IIS and get this error. I don't know what's the reason of it, because this site was created by another person, not me.

Stack trace:

```
`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +14370237
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value) +20
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.GetLiteralTraceData(LiteralControl literal, TraceData& data) +71
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.GetTraceData(Object renderedObject) +220
   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +47
   System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListenerList.EndRendering(TextWriter writer, Object renderedObject) +90
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +12372803
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +331
   System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +114
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) +151
   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +49
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) +246
   System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) +40
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +150
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5363`
```

Comment: Is your app pool running with the correct runtime version?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The PageInspector normally acts up if your server controls are out of date or are older versions. If you're using external ASP.NET Server controls, try to upgrade them.

And if a workaround is fine for you, then you can disable page inspector as follows:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: Added this string to web.config and the site started to launch. Thank you!

Comment: This was a life saver my friend I spent hours trying to upgrade an old Visual Studio 2010 Web Developer project to Visual Studio 2015 and could not get the damn web application to run properly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and Although [@raja nadar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25132159/1501497) fixed it for me it wasn't the actual cause (or as it turns out true fix).

The issue turned out to be:

```
optimizeCompilations="true"
```

Adding

```
<add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
```

Kicked it into a full recompile, where toggling false/true fixed the issue on a colleagues machine.

Seems I modified something not at the root that didn't trigger a re-compile of the relevant DLL's.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue in VS2017 Community Edition. Below is the observation, [Above post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25132159/1501497) was very useful to me.
Its only happen, when your visual studio is updated,(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidebb/2009/04/15/a-new-flag-to-optimize-asp-net-compilation-behavior/)
To turn on this switch, add it to your compilation section:

```
<compilation optimizeCompilations="true">
```

Or
Adding

```
<add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled" />
```

As mention above  posts